# Where is command v mapping in Vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

I have no idea how  got into my vim configuration, and its behavior is very wired.

```
:verbose imap
```

get

```
i  <C-R><C-R>  * <C-R>*
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/keymapping.vim line 43
!  <D-v>         <C-R>*
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What is `! <D-v>`? Why it has no file path?

BTW, in my .vimrc, I did `set nocomapatible` and using iterm 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is ! `<D-v>`?

From `:h key-notation`:

```
<D-...>     command-key (Macintosh only)    *<D-*
```

So, `<D-v>` is just <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

And prefix `!` in the imap results indicate that it's applicable for both insert mode and command-line mode.

> Why it has no file path?

Because this is vim built-in mapping, not set by user or a plugin and is coming from stand mac mappings. check `:h mac-standard-mappings`.